# UIAutomation how to drag a Slider

Tags: instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Im trying to slide a slider

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().sliders()[0].dragToValue(1.00);
```

This line Im using to slide it. It's not giving me any error but its not sliding too

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned IOS 7 Sim has issues with drags, but weirdly `dragToValue` seems to work with progress sliders.

This works for me:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().sliders()[0].dragToValue(0.5)
```

It's not very accurate though, and tends to hit the value, then go down to something like 0.4. 
Have you tried setting the value to < 1.0?

You might also try using `setValue()`

Answer (score 0):

What simulator are you running this in? UI automation and the iOS 7 simulator has problems recognizing "drags". If you have a developer account with apple, try running the automation from your device, that should solve the problem. If not, it isn't a iOS 7 simulator issue. If it does work, there might be other work arounds for your specific situation so you can test on the virtual device.